# set application icon for symbian aplication

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia

I have developed an application in Qt for symbian. 
Now i need to set the application icon. not the one showed on the application windows on the top left side. I need to set the icon which will be displayed in the menu of the symbian device! somebody pls help me on this.

I searched in here and found the ways to set the application icon but not the way i needed. All of them showed how to set the icon which will be displayed on the top left in the application window, as i said earlier this is not what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this into Symbian specific section of your .pro file:

```
symbian {
    ICON = ./resources/appIcon.svg
}
```